# Creating a string using StringBuilder in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, stringbuilder

I am in the process of converting a VB application. I am trying to create a string using StringBuilder as I cannot change a string using the Mid function. I have a loop although it only adds the first character to the string the rest is just white space. How can i add all the data to the string?

The code snippet is below; thanks for your help

```
        int table = 0;
        string tableData = Strings.StrDup(253, " ");
        int i = 0;
        string listData = null;
        int pointer =0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tableData);
        sb.Insert(0, Strings.StrDup(253, Strings.Chr(32)));
        sb.Insert(0, typeOfTable + Strings.Chr(0));


        pointer = 2;
        for (i = 0; i <= lstTABLE.Items.Count -1; i++)
        {
            listData = lstTABLE.Items[i].ToString();
            table = Convert.ToInt32(-(Conversion.Val(listData) * 10));
            sb.Insert(pointer, Functions.FNCodeTwoChar(table));
            pointer +=2;
        }

        sb.Insert (202,Functions.EncodeKP(Convert.ToSingle(Conversion.Val(lblStartTable.Text))));
        sb.Insert(205,Functions.EncodeKP(Convert.ToSingle(Conversion.Val(lblEndTable.Text))));
        sb.Insert(208, Strings.Space(36)); 
        sb.Insert(244, "   0");
        sb.Insert(248, "   0");
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Why do you use `StringBuilder.Insert`, requing you to manage stupid character pointers? Use [`StringBuilder.Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append.aspx)!

Comment: Thanks but no need to down vote

Comment: if I understand correctly, what you want is: `tableData = sb.ToString();`

Comment: The question clearly is "How can i add all the data to the string?". Come on guys, if you're not willing to help just don't do it. Down voting and calling stupid is not ok.

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo  The question was edited. First version did not clearly state the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35652763/revisions That's what the voting system is there for

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo I’m merely calling the manual management of insertion pointers stupid. The code adds a variable amount of data into the string builder (in that loop), yet the last few lines place content at a fixed position. That’s very likely a problem, and you could easily avoid this all if you simply appended instead of inserting at arbitrary locations.

Comment: Please give some examples of what is in `lstTable` and example output of `fnCodeTwoCharacters()`

Comment: @poke Not everybody here is an expert programmer. It may seem stupid to you but it may be the only way out for someone else. Pointing the issue is okay though, and I agree it has to be done, but there are other ways.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question of "I have a loop although it only adds the first character to the string the rest is just white space. How can i add all the data to the string?" is:

The second character you add to the string is Strings.Chr(0) which is the string terminator character. When C# (or VB.Net for that matter) hit this character it stops reading the string.